# Search for files on GitHub, where the repo has more than X stars

Tags: github

Is it possible to search GitHub for a particular filename AND restrict results to repos with some number of stars? I want to find all repositories that have a `wepack.config.json` file with 100+ stars.

**You can search for a particular file name like so:**

`filename:webpack.config.json`

**And you can search for repos with some number of stars like so:**

`stars:>100`

But there doesn't seem to be a way to combine the syntax to limit file searches.

Answer (score 3):

> But there doesn't seem to be a way to combine the syntax to limit file searches.

That is because [`stars:` is a repository selector](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#search-based-on-the-number-of-stars-a-repository-has), as opposed to [`filename:` which is a Code selector](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#search-by-filename).

You would need a [GitHub BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github) in order to effectively combine the two search criteria.
However, as the OP Don P adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847169/search-for-files-on-github-where-the-repo-has-more-than-x-stars/48847274#comment84699293_48847274):

> It looks like there is [no dataset for repos](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/bigquery-public-data:github_repos?pli=1).

Another approach would be using a [GitHub GraphQL query](https://developer.github.com/v4/), looking for:

- a [`TreeEntry`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/treeentry/),
- with [a `StarOrder`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/input_object/starorder/) for the result

Comment: Thanks @vonc wasn't aware of this dataset.  Sadly, it looks like there is no dataset for repos. https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/bigquery-public-data:github_repos?pli=1

Comment: @DonP OK. I have edited the answer to add an alternative approach.